# Minimum polynomial transformaton

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the rotation transformation of 120 degrees counter clockwise around the dot $(0,0)$. let $P(t) =t^7-t^4+t^3$. then $P(T)(x,y)= (x,y)$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

I need to find out if thats true or false, but I have no idea how to calculate $P(T)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $T$ rotates points $120^{\circ}$ counterclockwise, then:

$T^3$ rotates points $3 \cdot 120^{\circ} = 360^{\circ} \equiv 0^{\circ}$ counterclockwise,

$T^4$ rotates points $4 \cdot 120^{\circ} = 480^{\circ} \equiv 120^{\circ}$ counterclockwise,

$T^7$ rotates points $7 \cdot 120^{\circ} = 840^{\circ} \equiv 120^{\circ}$ counterclockwise.

Thus, $T^7$ and $T^4$ are equivalent, i.e. $T^7 = T^4$. Also, $T^3$ is the identity operation.

So, what is $P(T) = T^7-T^4+T^3$?

Comment: Then $P(T)$ is the identity as well.. so for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $P(T)(x,y) = (x,y) $. then it's true.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- $T$ is rotation by $120$ degree, so $T^3=T\circ T\circ T=Identity$.
- Determine $T^7, T^4$.
- What is $P(T)=T^7-T^4+T^3$? Then what is $P(T)(x,y)$?